# Como focar posição usando RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou com um problema em salvar a ultima posição de visualização do usuário, ex:

O usuário vai varrendo a lista e ao clicar em uma posição o app abre uma nova Activity e ao voltar para lista ele volta para o topo, no caso teria que voltar para a posição da ultima seleção.

Ja passei por isso e consegui resolver porém estava utilizando o ListView, utilizei o:

```
lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);    
  Parcelable posicaoFoco;
  posicaoFoco = lista.onSaveInstanceState();    
lista.onRestoreInstanceState(posicaoFoco);
```

Agora estou utilizando o RecyclerView mas o mesmo não aceita.

Comment: Edite melhor o código para facilitar a leitura, procure colocar códigos mais completos para ilustrar melhor sua duvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armazene a posição do item clicado e quando voltar você pode setar um scroll para a posição:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

A RecyclerView não tem esses métodos.

No entanto o LayoutManager que ela usa tem.

Pode aceder a eles usando

```
Parcelable recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState()
```

e

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
```

Note que na maioria das vezes não há necessidade de os utilizar já que internamente eles são usados pela RecyclerView para guardar o seu estado.